# can you UPDATE different rows in parallel on same table in SnowFlake

Tags: sql-update, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I was wondering if I could use UPDATE on different rows in the same table at the same time in snowflake. As in, can I get UPDATE statements to only lock the single row it is updating, and not lock the whole table?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results, as well as the `create table` statement for your table. As it stands, your question is too broad to be answered accurately.

Comment: I am not at the point of having a table even. I more or less cannot find the answer to "can you lock individual rows in SnowFlake table, as opposed to locking the whole table on UPDATE".  I am planning an execution strategy for multithreading a web scraping project.

Comment: Apparently Snowflake locks at the partition level but I've never actually seen this work so that two statements can mutate data in a table at the same time. It always seems to lock the entire table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't lock at a single row level in Snowflake.

My best suggestion is to do an `INSERT` only project, as these won't lock each other:

> Most INSERT and COPY statements write only new partitions. Those statements often can run in parallel with other INSERT and COPY operations, and sometimes can run in parallel with an UPDATE, DELETE, or MERGE statement.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/transactions.html

If you are planning to run a high number of concurrent `INSERT`, then consider switching to one of these approaches:

- Snowpipe
- Snowflake Connector for Kafka

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-pipelines-intro.html