# is snowflake locks the total table while updating few rows

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We have a big address table in snowflake which stores the different company addresses of 24 territories (states). There will be daily insert /updates for 24 states. The queries (procedures) will run parallel. I see queries were getting locked due to parallel runs.

while updating a specific territory(state) data, Is there any way to implement the table so that locks will happened only to that territory partition data? So queries can run parallel without blocks

Comment: [can you UPDATE different rows in parallel on same table in SnowFlake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64324418/can-you-update-different-rows-in-parallel-on-same-table-in-snowflake)

Comment: You might want to consider just doing all of the 24 territories in the same MERGE statement to handle your changes.